# adding enhanced ecommerce metrics to query

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery, enhanced-ecommerce

I've got this query that I'd like to add additional metric of "product details views" this is hits.ecommerceaction.action_type = 2.

I understand generally how these queries work, but this one is already complicated for me, and I'm struggling to add these additional nested hits into the mix.

This query I have already works to give me landing page and additional dimensions, so all I want to do now is add in product detail views.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   a.date
  ,a.landingpage
  ,a.medium
  ,a.sources
  ,a.campaign
  ,a.device
  ,a.content
  ,a.country
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)) sessions
  ,SUM(a.bounces) bounces
  ,SUM(a.trans) trans
  ,SUM(a.rev)/1000000 rev
  ,AVG(a.avg_pages) avg_pages
  ,(SUM(tos)/COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)))/60 session_duration
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(a.user)) users



FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) sessionId
      ,fullvisitorid user
      ,(SELECT sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName FROM UNNEST(hits) where hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) from UNNEST(hits) where type = 'PAGE')) country
      ,(SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE')) landingpage

      ,date
      ,trafficSource.medium medium
      ,trafficSource.source sources
      ,trafficSource.campaign campaign
      ,trafficSource.adContent content
      ,device.deviceCategory device
      ,totals.bounces bounces

      ,totals.timeonsite tos
      ,totals.transactions trans
      ,totals.transactionRevenue as rev
      ,(SELECT COUNT(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE') avg_pages



   FROM `ghd-analytics-235112.132444882.ga_sessions_*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20190417'   /*date start*/
    AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= '20190417'    /*date end*/ 
    AND totals.visits = 1   

) a
GROUP BY landingpage,medium,device,sources,campaign,content,date,country
ORDER BY sessions desc
```

Any thoughts/help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, which I had tried other variations of, but this seems to work now.

```
 ,(SELECT COUNT(eventinfo.eventaction) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventinfo.eventaction = 'productDetail') pviews
```

Full Query here for anyone else who would like it.

```
/* landing page, medium, source, campaign, adcontent, device, country, sessions, bounces, avg pages per session, time on site, transactions, revenue

   add additional dimensions and metrics into the second select statement, aggregate in the top select statement, order by any new dimensions

 */
 SELECT DISTINCT
   a.date
  ,a.landingpage
  ,a.medium
  ,a.sources
  ,a.campaign
  ,a.device
  ,a.content
  ,a.country
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)) sessions
  ,SUM(a.bounces) bounces
  ,SUM(a.trans) trans
  ,SUM(a.rev)/1000000 rev
  ,AVG(a.avg_pages) avg_pages
  ,(SUM(tos)/COUNT(DISTINCT(a.sessionId)))/60 session_duration
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT(a.user)) users
  ,sum(a.pviews) pviews



FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       CONCAT(CAST(fullVisitorId AS STRING),CAST(visitStartTime AS STRING)) sessionId
      ,fullvisitorid user
      ,(SELECT sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName FROM UNNEST(hits) where hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) from UNNEST(hits) where type = 'PAGE')) country
      ,(SELECT page.pagePath FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE hitnumber = (SELECT MIN(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE')) landingpage
       ,date
      ,trafficSource.medium medium
      ,trafficSource.source sources
      ,trafficSource.campaign campaign
      ,trafficSource.adContent content
      ,device.deviceCategory device
      ,totals.bounces bounces

      ,totals.timeonsite tos
      ,totals.transactions trans
      ,totals.transactionRevenue as rev
      ,(SELECT COUNT(hitnumber) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE type = 'PAGE') avg_pages
      ,(SELECT COUNT(eventinfo.eventaction) FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE eventinfo.eventaction = 'productDetail') pviews


   FROM `ghd-analytics-XXXXXX.XXXXXXX.ga_sessions_*`
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX >= '20190417'   /*date start*/
    AND _TABLE_SUFFIX <= '20190417'    /*date end*/ 
    AND totals.visits = 1   

) a


GROUP BY landingpage,medium,device,sources,campaign,content,date,country
ORDER BY sessions desc
```

Comment: I've reaslied this is actually just counting the standard "events" associated with the ecommerce payloads, and not the actual ecommerce hit, not that it really matters to me, but you'd have to adjust the eventaction part to match whatever your own events are.

Comment: So if anyone can still answer how it's done with the actual enhanced ecommerce hits that would still be valuable.  also bonus points if it's possible to add product sku in there also!

Comment: Try this [search string](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=eventinfo.eventaction+) in SO there are variety of questions around this topic. Maybe one will match